# Как "выхватить" часть сайта с помощью iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Скажем, мне надо "выхватить" из сайта определенную часть и она находится в самой середине сайта. Как мне так настроить iframe, что бы он её "захватил" ? Поискал такое в интернете, но ответов не нашёл :)

Answer (score 1):

Плохо искали [:)](http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3551148.htm).
Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/RwpJx/), а вот [оригинальный сайт](http://www.intellicast.com/National/Radar/Current.aspx?location=USNY0850). Только необходимо знать координаты определённой области.

Comment: а кроме CSS как нибудь ещё можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно взять элемент из айфрейма, если он находится на том же домене.

Answer (score 0):

Пришло на ум только использование `scrollTo(x,y)`.